# executing a bash script 100 times

Tags: bash

I am writing a shell script to choose randomly choose 200000 lines from a fastq file (Reads_qc.fastq), run a python script (counts.py) on the smaller file (file1.fastq) and count the number of lines in an output file (summary) which is produced by the python script.
This is my code,

```
cat Reads_qc.fastq |awk '{ printf("%s",$0); n++; if(n%4==0) { printf("\n");} else { printf("\t\t");} }' |shuf  |head -n 200000 |sed 's/\t\t/\n/g' |awk '{print $1 > "file1.fastq"}'

python counts.py file1.fastq > summary

wc -l summary
```

Can you suggest how I can make the script do these opeartions 100 times.

Comment: Assuming bash (per your tag) rather than `/bin/sh`: `for ((i=0; i<100; i++)); do ...stuff...; done`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a while loop and append the results of each to your summary file by using the '>>' operator instead of '>':

```
#!/bin/sh

count=100

while [ $count -lt 100 ]
do
    cat Reads_qc.fastq |awk '{ printf("%s",$0); n++; if(n%4==0) { printf("\n");} else { printf("\t\t");} }' |shuf  |head -n 200000 |sed 's/\t\t/\n/g' |awk '{print $1 > "file1.fastq"}'
    # Append to summary file instead of overwrite.
    python counts.py file1.fastq >> summary
    count=`expr $count + 1`
done
```

Comment: `while [ "$count" -lt 100 ]`, perhaps you mean? Without the spaces, this simply won't work; it'd be trying to find a command named `while[100`, and I doubt you have one installed on your machine.

Comment: Also, `count = 100` isn't an assignment either; it would need to be `count=100`, with _no_ spaces, to work at all (as it is, it'll call `count` as a command, with `=` as its first argument and `100` as its second).

Comment: ...and `cat foo | bar`  is extremely inefficient compared to `<foo bar` or `bar <foo` (same meaning, take your pick), as it passes a FIFO on stdin rather than a "real" file-backed descriptor.

Comment: Agreed. And I also agree that the OP's approach is inefficient. I was simply answering the question that was asked. I've edited my post to include proper spacing, thank you.

Comment: Even as edited, still trying to run a nonexisting command named `while[`.

Comment: Better -- though I'm not sure that appending to `summary` rather than rewriting it each time is in fact the desired goal. My impression is that the user wants to test that the amount of output from each run stay consistent.

Comment: Fixed that part as well.

Comment: (of course, this means that they don't have a good reason to write to a file at all rather than just connect their python script to `wc` with a pipe, but that's a whole 'nother item).